# Python - possible to only send message when keyword is detected in BOTH keyword lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, slack-api, praw

I have a python script that detects a keyword from a keyword list `keywords = ['camera', 'nikon']` and then sends a message to Slack like the following

Keyword **camera** detected

'Reddit post url'

'reddit comment that contains the keyword'

If the script detects a keyword from a second keyword list `color_keywords = ['red', 'blue']` then it posts the following

Keyword **camera** detected

'Reddit post url'

'reddit comment that contains the keyword'

**Color was detected**

My question is, am I somehow able to have the script so it ONLY sends a message if a keyword from EACH keyword list is found? 
So if it only finds a keyword from the first list, it will be ignored, if it finds one from the second list, it will also be ignored. but if it finds a keyword from BOTH lists, it will send the message to slack.

Below is my current code

````
MSG_TEMPLATE = """Keyword *{keyword}* detected
https://www.reddit.com{permalink}
```{comment_body}```"""

keywords = ['camera', 'nikon', 'canon']  
color_keywords = ['blue', 'red']

with open(save_path, 'r') as fp:
    alerted_comments = json.load(fp)

    for comment in comment_stream:
        if comment.id in alerted_comments:
            continue

        if comment.author:  # if comment author hasn't deleted
            if comment.author.name in ignore_users:
                continue

        if any(kw.lower() in comment.body.lower() for kw in keywords):
            found_kws = [kw for kw in keywords if kw.lower() in comment.body.lower()]

            msg = MSG_TEMPLATE.format(
                keyword=found_kws[0],
                permalink=comment.permalink,
                comment_body=comment.body
            )

            if any(kw.lower() in comment.body.lower() for kw in color_keywords):
                msg += "\n<!here> *A color was detected*"

            slack_data = {'text': msg, 'mrkdwn': True,}

            response = requests.post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/TB7AH6U2G/xxxxxxx/0KOjl9251TZExxxxxxxx',
                                             data=json.dumps(slack_data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
````

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Sure! The code below is excerpted for brevity:

```
def find_keywords(comment, word_list):
    """:returns: List of matching keywords present in the comment, or the empty list"""
    return [word for word in word_list if word.lower() in comment.body.lower()]

for comment in comment_stream:
    if not should_be_ignored(comment):
        found_kws = find_keywords(comment, keywords)
        found_colors = find_keywords(comment, color_keywords)

        if found_kws and found_colors:
            # At this point, we're guaranteed to have *both* one or more keywords *and* one or more colors
            send_message(comment, found_kws, found_colors)
```

The key insight here is: you create your lists of matches *first*, and then *afterward* examine them to decide if you want to send a message. In this case, only if *both* lists are not empty will you progress to sending the message.

(Implementation of `should_be_ignored()` and `send_message()` are, of course, left as an exercise to the reader. :) )

EDIT: Complete implementation of the original code:

````
def send_message(comment, keywords, colors):
    assert keywords and colors, "At this point, we should *only* be calling this function if we have at least one keyword and one color"

    MSG_TEMPLATE = """Keyword *{keyword}* and color *{color}* detected
    https://www.reddit.com{permalink}
    ```{comment_body}```"""
    msg = MSG_TEMPLATE.format(
        keyword=keywords[0],
        color=colors[0],
        permalink=comment.permalink,
        comment_body=comment.body
    )
    slack_data = {'text': msg, 'mrkdwn': True,}
    response = requests.post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/TB7AH6U2G/xxxxxxx/0KOjl9251TZExxxxxxxx',
                             data=json.dumps(slack_data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})


def should_be_ignored(comment, alerted):
    return comment.id in alerted or (comment.author and comment.author.name in ignore_users)


def find_keywords(comment, word_list):
    """:returns: List of matching keywords present in the comment, or the empty list"""
    return [word for word in word_list if word.lower() in comment.body.lower()]


keywords = ['camera', 'nikon', 'canon']  
color_keywords = ['blue', 'red']

with open(save_path, 'r') as fp:
    alerted_comments = json.load(fp)

for comment in comment_stream:
    if not should_be_ignored(comment, alerted_comments):
        found_kws = find_keywords(comment, keywords)
        found_colors = find_keywords(comment, color_keywords)

        if found_kws and found_colors:
            # At this point, we're guaranteed to have *both* one or more keywords *and* one or more colors
            send_message(comment, found_kws, found_colors)
````

Note that all I've done (aside from the new requirement that we have *both* a color and a keyword before sending a message) is to pull out some of your business logic into the `should_be_ignored()` and `send_message()` functions, hopefully clarifying the intent of the main body of code. This should be a drop-in replacement for the sample you started with.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering!. 
I have been trying to format it into my code, but am having trouble of where to put it and what  to take out of my current code?
Would it be possible if you could show me how I would format it? Sorry, I am new to python and just trying to get my head around it haha

Comment: @Vestipial, edited to include the complete sample you provided. :) And, erm... sorry I can't help myself with the refactorings...

Comment: haha wow, thank you so much!, yep, I am just too new at python to have figured that out haha. 
So I have put the code in and tried to sort everything myself, but now I am getting the following error
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fudbot-client.py", line 37, in <module>
    keyword=keywords[0],
NameError: name 'keywords' is not defined`

I tried for a while messing around with the code, but it didn't help haha.

I have pasted the entire script, maybe I have just missed a line somewhere?
https://pastebin.com/hj4JSyhR

Once again, thank you for your detailed help!

Comment: Looks like the indentation on your `send_message()` is broken. Lines 30 through 43 in your PasteBin link should all be indented as part of the `send_message()` definition. And you'll probably want to move your response-handling code (lines 75 through 93) into `send_message()` as well.

Comment: Thank you,
I got them all sorted out, Now I have a strange one.

I get no errors, the script runs, shows the reddit username (so I guess it logged in) 
but then the script just ends. but with no errors or  anything. it just jumps back to the command prompt which is strange?
https://pastebin.com/m8tu2LRn

Comment: I'd say add some `print()` logging to figure out where your assumptions have been violated—maybe the comment stream is just empty?

Comment: Thanks, I did add it where I knew. I enabled logging for PRAW and it does indeed succeed in connecting.
You were right, I had not put the comment stream in so I added the following
`comment_stream = subreddit.stream.comments()` But it just does the same thing and shows login only. I did a print() on that and it came up with `<generator object stream_generator at 0x000001811FB75480>`

The code here works perfectly https://pastebin.com/QMEUbD40 but I just cant figure out where the link is for the other one. sorry to bother, you dont need help out if you like, you have done so much already.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know anything about the packages you're using for Reddit or Slack. :/ I'd suggest putting together a separate question. Sorry I can't be more helpful.